# Core Data - Data not being stored in database

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7, singleton

I created an application that uses `Core Data` I am not using the app delegate in this app. There isn't an error in the  `[managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]`. I've been struggling with this for two days.. Can someone please tell me what I am missing? Any help will be appreciated. My code is as follows:

DatabaseHelper.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface DatabaseHelper : NSObject


@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext;
+ (id)sharedInstance;

@end
```

DatabaseHelper.m

```
#import "DatabaseHelper.h"

@implementation DatabaseHelper
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;

static DatabaseHelper *sharedInstance = nil;

+ (DatabaseHelper *)sharedInstance {
    if (sharedInstance != nil) {
        return sharedInstance;
    }

    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[DatabaseHelper alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext {

    if (__managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return __managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
    }
    return __managedObjectContext;
}

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {

    if (__managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Database" withExtension:@"momd"];
    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return __managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeUrl =  [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database.sqlite"];
    NSLog(@"Location: %@", storeUrl);
    NSError *error;
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: [self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error]) {
        // Handle the error.
    }

    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application's documents directory

/**
 Returns the path to the application's documents directory.
 */
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DatabaseHelper.h"
#import "Friends.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *labelText;
-(IBAction)pressButton:(id)sender;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    managedObjectContext = [[DatabaseHelper sharedInstance] managedObjectContext];

    NSArray *names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      @"Steve",
                      @"John",
                      @"Paul",
                      nil];

    int startingAge = 25;

    for (NSString *name in names) {
        Friends *friend = (Friends*) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Friends" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        [friend setName:name];
        [friend setAge:[NSNumber numberWithInt:startingAge]];
         startingAge++;

         NSError *error = nil;
         if ([managedObjectContext save:&error])
         NSLog(@"%@", name);
         }



}
-(IBAction)pressButton:(id)sender{

        NSError *error = nil;
       managedObjectContext =  [[DatabaseHelper sharedInstance]managedObjectContext];
        if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Saved!!");
            if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                abort();
            } 
        }
    }
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: How are you determining that the data is not saved? I ran your code, and it worked for me (I did a fetch request in viewDidLoad, the second time I launched the app, and commented out all the code except getting the moc).

Comment: @rdelmar Shouldn't the records be added to the SQLite database?

Comment: @rdelmar that's the issue that I have. I looked in the Database.sqlite file and the table is empty. Totally lost on how the data is being display if the table is empty.

Comment: So, the data is being displayed? If so, what's the problem?

Comment: @rdelmar just wanted to make sure the data is being stored properly and not just being cached.

Answer (score 0):

I trust you realize that you are creating new records every time the view controller is accessed?  `-viewDidLoad` will fire every time.

Also, you are not checking for the error after your save in the `-viewDidLoad`.  The code should read:

```
for (NSString *name in names) {
    Friends *friend = (Friends*) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Friends" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [friend setName:name];
    [friend setAge:[NSNumber numberWithInt:startingAge]];
    startingAge++;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if ([managedObjectContext save:&error])
        NSLog(@"%@", name);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
    }
}
```

Next, you are not checking for an error when adding your `NSPersistentStore` to the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.  If you do not have a `NSPersistentStore` (because of a failure) you would not see anything written to a file.  Might not be your issue but you should always log the error:

```
NSError *error;
__persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: [self managedObjectModel]];
if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error adding store: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
}
```

Finally, you **do not** need to cast the results of `-[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: inManagedObjectContext:]`. That method returns an `id` and no cast is needed.  You should consider casting in Objective-C to be "lying to the compiler" and bad.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that this is an issue with `Xode 5` I ran my code on a `Xcode 4.6.3` and it worked as it should I was able to see the records in the `SQLite` database. Don't know if this is a bug or if Apple as stopped adding records to the database for security reasons. Hope this helps someone.

Update

After further research I found that the `-wal` file causes the data not to be added to the database 
after adding the below to my code it's now showing in the database.

```
NSDictionary *options = @{ NSSQLitePragmasOption : @{@"journal_mode" : @"DELETE"} };
```